# Do people's backs arch when receiving an electric shock?

Tags: biology

[PathologyExpert.com](http://www.pathologyexpert.com/boards/forensics/felectric.htm) says of bodies that have been electrocuted:

> May arch back and neck backwards.

Many times in movies and TV shows, actors arch their backs when exposed to electricity.

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 2):

Referring to US National Library of [Medicine](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003200.htm), electrical shock/injury is known to cause seizures.

Seizures categorized as myoclonic are typically characterized by increase in tone in the extensor muscles causing the back to arch. These seizures are compared to being jolted by a mild electric shock.

> An abrupt increase in tone in the extensor muscles will cause the head to be thrown back, the back to arch, the legs to extend, the arms to stiffen. Any or all of these movements may occur during a myoclonic jerk. If they occur while a child is standing, he may be suddenly thrown backward to the ground, or he may suddenly be thrown forward to the ground, perhaps hitting his/her face, breaking a tooth, or causing a facial laceration.

Source: [Myoclonic seizures](http://doosesyndrome.org/mae-explained/myoclonic-seizures)

Comment: Note the difference between linking the first (random) word of the quote, and linking the name of the title that you have quoted from to the actual full text.

Comment: Noted, going to use this tip for my future answers!